# Why don't I have the 'coffee' command?

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, installation

I have node and npm on my Centos 7 instance.  I did a

```
sudo npm -g install coffee
```

And it reported no errors.  But I don't have a coffee executable, which was kind of the point.

```
%: type -a coffee
coffee not found
%: type -a Coffee
Coffee not found
```

It seems like I should need something for NPM on my `$PATH`. If I knew what to add, I would try that.

I'm not sure how to debug this, sorry.  I've tried this:

```
%: npm bin
/home/jonea/node_modules/.bin
```

Interestingly, that's not a directory that exists:

```
%: ls -la ~/node_modules
total 12
drwxr-xr-x  3 jonea compgen 4096 Jun  6 10:34 .
drwxr-xr-x 33 jonea compgen 4096 Jun  7 09:33 ..
drwxr-xr-x  4 jonea compgen 4096 Jun  6 10:34 coffee
```

And, no, there are no executables in that coffee directory.

If anyone has ideas about other debugging I can do, I'll append the results here.

Comment: You basically downloaded some `.js` files via npm - aka a node module, why'd you expect it to deliver binaries?

Comment: Are you aware of that the module you installed has nothing to do with CoffeeScript? See this page https://www.npmjs.com/package/coffee Is it what you expect?

Comment: @Molda -- that was it. Many thanks.  If you want credit, make it an answer, otherwise I'll give it to huaoguo.

Comment: Cool, I will add it as an answer thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The package you installed has nothing to do with CoffeeScript check this [npm coffee](https://www.npmjs.com/package/coffee)

You need different package

```
npm install -g coffeescript
```

Answer (score -1):

sudo npm -g install coffee-script

Comment: Thanks to @Molda I understand that you are technically correct.  But as far as I am concerned, this is not answer to the queston, nor did it actually help me.  Sorry.